# ContainsKey equivalent for AppFabric cache

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

We'll be populating the cache ahead of time, rather than on-demand, and it would help to have an efficient ContainsKey-equivalent that **only** tests whether the specific key is stored, without the overheads of serialization/deserialization and pulling the content over the wire that come from `Get(key) != null`.

Bizarrely, I can't find anything in the API to achieve this. Does anyone know of a workaround? Tags aren't really an option, since they'd require named regions, and we really need the resilence of a distributed cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfornately, there is no method to do this in Windows Server AppFabric (neither in Azure Cache).

The best you can do is an extension method like this one

```
public static bool Contains(this DataCache dataCache, string key)
{
    return dataCache.Get(key) != null;
}
```

You have to pay the *Serialization Tax* which can be problematic. It depends on you context.

The only workaround I know is by using regions : [CreateRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.datacache.createregion%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) returns false if the region already exists. Never tested how it scales, but I don't think so.